# What is a template in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am reading Rails and many places I see this word "template" ?  Is it short for "View Templates" and by that do they mean for example an index.html.erb or show.html.haml file in the View folder?

For example here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html when they talk about rendering a template:

> If you want to render the view that corresponds to a different action
>   within the same template, you can use render with the name of the
>   view:

And what do they mean by "`rendering`"?  Well sometimes we say

> render

and we mean go to another page? sometimes not. I mean I can't understand the difference between "render" and `"redirect_to"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rails, template and view address more or less the same thing. Where view is the "visual representation of a resource", template is the specific representation. So, a view usually has a representation per format, meaning you will have html template, js template, xml template, and so on.

Render means resolve your templates into strings to be sent as the body of your http response. Usually you render a template as the body of your response. Inside this template you can use the #render call to render sub-components, what in Rails are called partials, html snippets which are used in more than one place, and therefore can be reused. You also use #render inside a controller action within the respond_to clause to address the template you want to render, which is what that bit you posted means.

Render means your response will have a body. redirect_to instructs the browser they need to "go somewhere else" and this response doesn't have a body, hence doesn't render anything. To understand what this means thoroughly you must read a bit about the HTTP protocol.